# How add a listview to to other listview footer

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview & add another listview in footer to first one.All row of footer listview is not showing.

**Adding Footer**

footerView = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.species_fav_footer, null);
 list_fav.addFooterView(footerView);

**footer.xml**

1. ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/saltWater"
       style="@style/BlueTitleBar"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:text="Saltwater"
       />

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list_fav_species_salt"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
       android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"

       />
   ```

Comment: Why are you adding 2 ListViews, instead you can implement **Sectioned ListView**.

Comment: there is problem to remove favourite on touch.

Comment: You can use Expandable ListView

Comment: wht prob u r facing in remove favo on touch ?

Comment: Agree with Aamir's point, you can use **Expandable ListView** with some customization.

Comment: Expandable ListView is not app requirement.

Comment: can we remove expand & collapse property of expandable Listview?